# Screen Recording Software to capture Software Defects

Tags: screen, capture, software-quality, recording

do you know a good screen recording software, to assist the quality management process? I think, that the following features will be important:

- easy to use.
- auto capturing the last 5 or 10 Minutes
- small video size
- low price :-)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snagit good for screenshots, Techsmith Camtasia more screencast oriented or a free Techsmith version which is Techsmith Jing http://www.techsmith.com/jing/  which is pretty clean.

Comment: Thank you very much. Jing seems to be the ideal solution. I will try it out.

Comment: it's problem it saves video as swf

Answer (score 4):

[BlueBerry FlashBack](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/BBFlashBack_FreePlayer.aspx) is pretty much spot on. Just found it today. Express edition does it, and that's free. Set it to record continuously, and keep the last x minutes, or by filesize. 2 minutes resulted in just a hair under 3MB file (compressed in BB's proprietary format), and was just under 30MB memory; doing 6 minutes now and it's around 37-38MB, don't know file size yet. Mostly hovering ~11% of processor power, spiking occasionally to 18 or 22.

Comment: Very good finding. I really like that it can record the screen, a video source (like my webcam) and audio simultaneously and you can cut and create a custom render later on to AVI.

Comment: saves videos as flr :(

Comment: As of 2016, free version saves to AVI and SWF. The free version seems very powerful. For video editing and annotations, you need the commercial versions.

Answer (score 2):

I find [Techsmith's SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) very handy when I need to capture images or videos